# Alert box has to be present in order for html() and dialog to work properly in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this very strange behavior.

The code below works properly (fetching the html from the Action in the controller) only if an alert box is displayed before the dialog opens.

```
 var ticks;

    function InitializeDialog($element) {

        var t;
        $.get(approveAction + "?ticks=" + ticks, function (data) {
           t = data;
        });
        //alert(t);
        $element.html(t);

        $element.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 650,
            height: 600,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            model: true,
            show: 'slide',
            closeText: 'x',
            dialogClass: 'alert',
            closeOnEscape: true,


            close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                window.location.reload();
            }

        });

    }

    $("#cal").on('click', ".events", function () {
        ticks = $(this).attr('value');
        InitializeDialog($("#comments"));


        $("#comments").dialog("open");
    });
```

The dialog will be displayed empty if I keep the alert(t) as a comment whereas if I uncomment it everything works as intended. Similar code works correctly elsewhere in the application.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perform operation's with dynamically loaded content's inside `.get` Callback

```
$.get(approveAction + "?ticks=" + ticks, function (data) {
           t = data;
           // Perform operation's here
           $element.html(t);
           //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. Do you know why it wouldn't work before? Also it would not work If I used $element.load(approveAction + "?ticks=" + ticks) in the InitializeDialog on dialog open(). At any rate thanks again.

Comment: the reason your code was not working without alert is that, the data which you are getting using get is not availabe instantly for use, so putting an alert simulated kind of a delay which makes the data to be available for use